# How html compiler understands the angularJS?

Tags: html, asp.net, angularjs

I am a newbie to angularJS and wondered how the directives and templates compiled in html form. Is there any background work in rendering of HTML form ?

Comment: You should read this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler